# SVG Image with <image> tags does not show up in Firefox 16 when referred through GWT application

Tags: firefox, gwt, svg

I am facing this issue in Firefox 16.

I created a new `svg` file (NewImage.svg) with `<image>` tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'
          'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
 xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
 width="224px" height="54px" viewBox="-0.58 -1.162 224 54">
     <image xlink:href='background.svg' width='224' height='54' />
     <image xlink:href='foreground.svg' x='12' y='12' width='32' height='32'/>
</svg>
```

When I open this `NewImage.svg` in Firefox directly, it opens perfectly.

However, when I refer to this svg file from inside my `GWT` application, the `NewImage.svg` does not load in Firefox 16. It does load correctly in IE 9.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet which shows how this SVG file is used in GWT application?

Comment: I use mxGraph for my Visualzer module in my GWT application. It needs me to pass relative path of the SVG file in the 'style' parameter for mxgraph.insertVertex() method as:
style=node;shape=image;image=<relativePathToTheSVGFile>

Answer (score 1):

Gecko does not allow SVG loaded inside  to load any external resources, for security reasons (basically to prevent images from phoning home when users won't expect them to).  So you need to put any resources you want to use into data: URIs

Comment: Could you please give me an example on providing Data URIs for SVG files inside another SVG file?

Comment: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/cb573b9307e5/layout/reftests/svg/use-extref-dataURI-01.svg

Comment: Thanks for the example Boris!

I tried:
      <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,http://127.0.0.1:8888/images/background.svg" width='224' height='54'/>
      <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,http://127.0.0.1:8888/images/foreground.svg" x='12' y='12' width='32' height='32'/>

Can't I point to svg files like this?

Should I read the svg file and paste it's content inside "data:image/svg+xml," ?

Comment: I even tried:
      <use xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,http://127.0.0.1:8888/images/Warning-group_2b.svg" width='224' height='54'/>

This didn't work either. Can't I point to SVG files through URLs?

Comment: You must put the image contents as the data url. You **cannot** link to external files from an image.

Comment: Having image contents inside a data url only works in Firefox. It does not work in IE9!
I tried this image:
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/cb573b9307e5/layout/reftests/svg/use-extref-dataURI-01.svg

This image shows 'lime' colour in Firefox and Red in IE9. That means IE is ignoring the <use> tag completely.

Is there any alternative to 'Include other svg images inside an SVG image and it should get displayed similarly in both IE and Firefox' ?

Comment: @TilakSharma IE9 works properly as per the spec actually, with e.g. `xlink:href="yourimage.png"`