# D3 Firefox issue showing graph incorrect - not showing any SVG at all

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg, d3.js

So this is how it shall look like (**Chrome** browser):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1AY7.png

There everything is fine and really fast.

But accidentially I tested my prototype with the **Firefox** and I don't know know what is going on there. Here is picture of the same example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg0Dt.png

- markers are not correctly drawed (look at the arrows, there are somehow strange line, in Crhome everything is fine)
- the svg's are not loaded (if I take instead png's it also works in Firefox, so this is a svg issue somehow)
- and it's really slow (but maybe that is normal because Chrome has a better performance in JS?)

Here is another picture of the HTML code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btYwP.png

Showing you the image svg thing. As you can see the code is valid.

So yeah what is going on? Why does Firefox have so many problems? Are there errors in the HTML code? I already validated it and didn't find anything.

Already tried:

- to delete the circle, maybe it was in the front in the Firefox ( but as you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2ur9.png that was not the case) I delete the first circle. And now the place is empty there. So you can see it's not an z-index issue at all. Must be anything else, because as I said if I take a png there instead it works.
- I also tested: 
  *image class="svgimage svgimagePerson" href="pics/node_person.svg" x="-20px" y="-20px" width="40px" height="40px"*
  But the same thing. Still now shown the svg in the Firefox.
- Ohh and not to forget the both classes are empty. I want to use them later on when everything is working. So currently they are just placeholders but they have no influence on this issue.

What else could I try to do. Loading svg via background-image? But I really would like to know the reason for running in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Any help is welcome especially the SVG loading issue. Thank you.

### Graph initializing code

```
function initializeGraph(){
    zoom.on("zoom", zoomed);
    drag.on("dragstart", dragstart);

    force
        .size([width, height])
        .gravity(.1)
        .charge(-400)
        .friction(0.9)
        .theta(0.9) 
        .linkStrength(0.9)
        .distance(55)
        .alpha(0.1)
        .on("tick", tick);
    force.start();
    svg = d3.select("#main-right")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
    svg
        .append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["end"]) 
        .enter().append("svg:marker")   
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 32)
        .attr("refY", -0.05)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .attr('fill', '#359AF4');

    container = svg.append("g");

    link = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

    node = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click",        function(d) { click(d); })
        .on("dblclick",     function(d) { dblclick(d); })
        .on('contextmenu',  function(data, index) {
                                                d3.event.preventDefault();
                                                updateGraphByRemoveElement(data, index);
                                        })
        .call(drag);    
    node
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "bgcircle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .style("fill", '#eee')
        .style("stroke", '#fff')
        .style("stroke-width", '0.5px');
    node
        .append("image")
        .attr("class","svgimage svgimagePerson")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
                                            if (d.class == "Person") {
                                                return "pics/node_person.svg";
                                            } else {
                                                return "pics/node_appln.svg";
                                        }} )
        .attr("x", "-20px")
        .attr("y", "-20px")
        .attr("width", "40px")
        .attr("height", "40px");
    node
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "nodetext")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 4)
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });  
    node
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "linkcountercircle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", -16);
    node
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "linkcountertext")
        .attr("x", -3)
        .attr("y", -13)
        .text(function(d) { return d.linkCount; });
    setzoom();
}
```

### The SVG file that does not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="appln.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-516.42857"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1784"
     inkscape:window-height="998"
     inkscape:window-x="1397"
     inkscape:window-y="2"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer4"
     inkscape:label="Kreis"
     style="display:none">
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:#d7d1d7;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="path4757"
       sodipodi:cx="502.85715"
       sodipodi:cy="502.85715"
       sodipodi:rx="500"
       sodipodi:ry="500"
       d="m 1002.8571,502.85715 a 500,500 0 1 1 -999.9999528,0 500,500 0 1 1 999.9999528,0 z" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-52.362183)"
     style="display:inline">
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:6;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="rect2993"
       width="611.33856"
       height="646.02979"
       x="194.33067"
       y="240.5731"
       ry="55.467205" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="Layer"
     style="display:inline">
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;display:inline"
       id="path3777"
       d="m 282.61027,386.12047 c 1.5219,-0.68605 3.0837,-1.28961 4.5656,-2.05814 2.0565,-1.0665 8.0581,-4.57512 6.0381,-3.44099 -35.9669,20.19393 -35.5519,21.01611 -20.0669,10.42619 2.8209,-1.92919 5.6323,-3.87282 8.418,-5.85257 2.7755,-1.97255 5.5099,-4.00246 8.2648,-6.00369 11.9369,-8.99036 23.6675,-18.25753 35.8556,-26.90883 -6.7421,6.25644 34.234,-32.30056 47.7826,-21.04814 5.0822,4.22079 7.4032,11.27585 9.9237,17.08081 6.0372,16.62043 10.983,33.60845 17.4233,50.08315 3.3086,6.99982 6.2525,14.69206 11.6725,20.42923 2.4073,2.54811 4.5985,3.76683 7.4922,5.69617 1.5463,0.52856 3.0175,1.38129 4.6388,1.58569 6.8519,0.86386 13.7248,-2.88592 19.424,-6.0595 2.664,-1.48346 10.5161,-6.17442 7.8394,-4.71395 -9.0085,4.91532 -17.8933,10.05413 -26.84,15.0812 15.2681,-10.19656 30.7768,-20.01291 46.0701,-30.17136 15.2232,-11.07461 30.9494,-19.63299 47.9213,-28.94724 0.903,-0.49554 2.0498,-0.54939 3.0662,-0.38253 2.8035,0.46027 4.3643,2.59488 6.2758,4.4023 8.0224,9.50121 14.7288,20.09443 21.8795,30.27303 6.4598,8.92388 11.1783,14.63279 22.3213,16.58278 7.1265,0.44393 13.6329,-1.8148 19.8419,-5.12267 1.6152,-0.86048 6.3225,-3.68893 4.7267,-2.79307 -10.6038,5.95286 -21.1678,11.97641 -31.7517,17.96461 -1.4894,12.53362 28.1966,-27.86328 43.59,-22.39572 5.3481,1.89956 14.7708,10.68441 19.2426,14.44207 6.9742,5.66186 13.7877,12.81557 23.5796,11.99084 5.7454,-0.48391 8.8284,-2.59482 13.9567,-5.06489 -51.8801,31.70654 -24.6074,13.65632 -13.6637,2.02276 6.1828,-6.57257 11.7784,-13.7053 17.4507,-20.71282 7.1152,-8.78922 14.029,-17.77706 22.2018,-25.62149 2.9005,-2.87878 6.4774,-4.8409 9.8697,-7.04643 0,0 39.4189,-15.80282 39.4189,-15.80282 l 0,0 c -3.1008,2.91565 -6.9134,4.40145 -10.3226,6.90486 -8.6456,7.58247 -15.9341,16.41684 -23.1452,25.35713 -7.8892,9.65737 -15.5761,19.52065 -24.3873,28.3712 -2.2901,2.30044 -4.3149,4.96668 -7.0441,6.72402 -13.9736,8.99745 -28.5923,16.95133 -42.8884,25.427 -6.2513,2.19143 -8.7619,3.81157 -15.4576,3.38813 -10.13,-0.64062 -17.38,-7.86941 -24.8374,-13.84808 -4.5467,-3.65042 -9.3451,-8.20004 -14.709,-10.67846 -1.0152,-0.46905 -2.1371,-0.83422 -3.2552,-0.81164 -1.0275,0.0207 -3.8138,1.47346 -2.9374,0.9367 10.6664,-6.53257 21.5846,-12.64456 32.3769,-18.96685 -13.297,7.89387 -26.5322,15.89278 -39.891,23.6816 -8.0639,4.70164 -17.2572,7.06794 -26.5386,5.55806 -11.2436,-3.31412 -17.1903,-9.79468 -23.6916,-19.32935 -6.8201,-9.90358 -13.2732,-20.33579 -21.6866,-28.95663 -2.0345,-1.18719 -1.9559,-1.78153 -4.1041,-1.06058 -0.8053,0.27024 -3.0261,1.53983 -2.2951,1.10715 60.6206,-35.88389 35.8417,-21.98229 23.5874,-12.69755 -15.5545,10.03418 -31.0762,20.12858 -46.4887,30.37669 -14.4857,8.57755 -28.928,17.22871 -43.457,25.73265 -10.9389,6.40261 -23.0373,12.52922 -35.26,5.81641 -3.5712,-2.59468 -5.1932,-3.47287 -8.1394,-6.81515 -5.4949,-6.23371 -8.5669,-14.22163 -11.8415,-21.71809 -6.1587,-16.48782 -11.0686,-33.4051 -17.4027,-49.82774 -1.9153,-4.13883 -4.1512,-11.52881 -8.7516,-13.84323 -2.5234,-1.26951 -6.447,1.32706 -5.5784,0.79588 10.4731,-6.40522 21.1622,-12.45045 31.7434,-18.67567 -12.6729,8.39995 -24.5152,17.98739 -36.6784,27.09396 -24.7109,18.27208 -50.4545,35.76406 -78.67989,48.13753 0,0 33.33199,-26.09393 33.33199,-26.09393 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;display:inline"
       id="path3779"
       d="m 282.06867,568.36093 c 1.2904,-0.70367 2.5808,-1.40734 3.8713,-2.11101 -10.2843,5.89133 -20.4818,11.93667 -30.8527,17.67399 -1.9879,1.09975 3.8367,-2.43779 5.6891,-3.75317 5.7073,-4.05294 11.0371,-8.65674 16.4092,-13.13373 8.7284,-7.82004 17.8822,-15.17414 26.302,-23.33131 12.6121,-13.56953 30.6888,-35.44486 50.1675,-30.51101 6.7451,4.23055 11.6736,10.91751 16.7039,16.97727 6.6667,7.83884 13.931,14.59564 23.3704,18.80498 12.3136,4.50635 25.1184,3.26313 37.7309,0.99993 7.8035,-1.74823 15.38,-4.56975 22.3887,-8.43264 1.5419,-0.84986 6.0608,-3.5858 4.5283,-2.71896 -10.5908,5.99069 -21.1366,12.06085 -31.7049,18.09127 5.6576,-3.18892 9.5936,-8.14438 13.685,-13.00115 30.7268,-19.46056 33.0288,-31.00075 46.7531,-11.60983 4.3026,7.27522 9.9197,13.6508 15.4188,20.03509 6.9758,8.31175 16.6301,10.4899 26.8879,11.8354 14.5435,0.89509 28.7121,-1.36165 42.3603,-6.27752 9.8831,-4.46247 18.0421,-9.05418 28.9645,-6.23198 9.1966,2.95039 18.4819,3.85755 28.0462,2.8705 13.9384,-3.20338 26.2472,-10.62696 38.6708,-17.38938 -4.7265,2.71756 17.3488,-10.00361 13.0022,-7.5191 -9.9376,5.68029 -39.6913,22.82404 -29.7921,17.07702 13.4726,-7.8216 26.903,-15.71994 40.5125,-23.30083 1.2354,-0.68814 2.5747,-1.28789 3.9756,-1.48039 1.3057,-0.17942 2.6229,0.26233 3.9344,0.39349 8.9601,4.62909 14.6891,13.77651 20.5898,21.67851 0,0 -36.0118,21.36269 -36.0118,21.36269 l 0,0 c -3.6087,-4.82577 -10.3737,-15.06423 -15.909,-17.52751 -0.844,-0.37556 -1.8139,-0.35075 -2.7208,-0.52612 -0.9831,0.23999 -2.0003,0.36826 -2.9491,0.71999 -1.2107,0.44885 -4.6053,2.32967 -3.4957,1.6692 10.2464,-6.09918 41.2203,-23.99804 30.9187,-17.99269 -18.0645,10.53065 -36.057,21.21092 -54.3063,31.42692 -12.6798,6.89093 -25.5456,14.22702 -40.0678,16.22662 -9.8794,0.41867 -19.4127,-0.96875 -28.976,-3.47089 -9.6792,-0.76664 -18.3575,4.14671 -27.1802,7.48373 -14.1833,4.31521 -28.8663,6.31373 -43.7021,4.84612 -11.146,-1.84754 -21.2404,-5.1998 -28.7245,-14.20243 -5.5663,-6.49618 -11.2954,-12.91274 -15.9009,-20.14476 -1.3209,-1.76521 -2.6,-3.84897 -4.4869,-5.09218 -1.4629,-0.96387 -1.9629,0.30944 -1.581,0.0933 11.8575,-6.71042 23.6819,-13.47916 35.5228,-20.21873 -5.9617,1.04382 -8.2864,10.92929 -14.3429,13.01291 -21.8697,12.85221 -42.3781,28.56261 -67.6407,33.33741 -13.2939,1.81162 -26.683,2.36465 -39.3448,-2.93616 -9.6914,-4.90126 -17.3566,-12.03088 -24.367,-20.29493 -3.7346,-4.40284 -9.2315,-12.5031 -15.1719,-13.64622 -14.1527,5.15793 -0.4929,0.28367 32.9975,-19.48851 0.6959,-0.4108 -1.5407,0.53327 -2.2236,0.96529 -3.1717,2.00674 -5.328,5.27135 -7.7178,8.05673 -8.3816,8.44446 -17.74,15.76469 -26.5162,23.79017 -6.8571,5.7727 -14.0361,12.78916 -21.7151,17.38448 -13.5221,8.09202 -27.2149,15.89529 -40.8314,23.82725 -1.3608,0.79269 -2.73369,1.56443 -4.10051,2.34664 0,0 32.93231,-26.64378 32.93231,-26.64378 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;display:inline"
       id="path3781"
       d="m 282.98947,718.12461 c 4.9527,2.15041 10.9153,3.68482 16.1839,1.50698 1.4919,-0.61666 5.5219,-3.34312 4.1063,-2.56735 -10.49,5.74852 -20.8902,11.65928 -31.3353,17.48891 8.6816,-6.58913 13.9911,-16.04156 18.5217,-25.71883 2.6215,-6.17185 4.9888,-12.4938 6.6558,-18.99541 4.7218,-18.24246 12.4012,-14.44159 40.1142,-27.70729 0.1886,-0.0903 5.3479,3.81848 5.4141,3.86789 6.6337,5.95018 13.5988,11.44947 21.0967,16.27034 8.9783,4.63442 17.4982,10.99042 27.2449,14.01399 2.18,0.67626 4.4556,0.99322 6.6834,1.48983 21.0197,1.1341 40.8067,-7.20508 59.7446,-15.30434 12.6072,-6.16764 47.6615,-25.5382 -9.6728,6.49056 -2.1599,1.20659 4.206,-2.60665 6.2991,-3.92572 4.4294,-2.7914 5.5844,-3.57037 9.8128,-6.33573 13.9237,-9.82374 32.5967,-41.90432 49.5217,-26.82673 4.9374,4.85579 9.6609,9.91583 14.8677,14.48819 5.6573,4.76851 10.3465,4.93025 17.4209,4.98489 5.4673,-0.86894 11.22,-1.8722 16.2921,-4.22571 10.2621,-4.7618 -3.1328,0.57867 6.5847,-3.16 0.942,-0.13033 1.8835,-0.5178 2.8259,-0.39098 6.3457,0.85388 13.4308,10.16669 17.6956,14.39074 7.0727,7.3289 14.7568,14.04866 24.1151,18.22289 7.2445,2.13236 12.7624,0.51085 19.3333,-2.43954 2.5447,-0.82673 4.8884,-1.67945 7.2618,-2.87411 0.7004,-0.35253 2.8263,-1.3525 2.1474,-0.96013 -40.5616,23.44378 -45.4995,26.5989 -32.7612,18.55775 1.3776,0.75362 3.052,-3.08015 3.1042,-3.11058 37.5454,-21.8618 25.7531,-28.92109 39.363,-19.99817 3.9797,1.93668 8.0463,3.27416 12.4089,4.0958 7.5786,2.48437 15.5764,2.75429 23.3576,4.16146 8.1588,2.00878 16.4479,1.20508 24.7188,0.64744 7.0678,-1.41797 14.1647,-2.59219 21.3467,-3.22368 4.7587,0.46406 2.3864,0.20891 7.117,0.76491 0,0 -34.3858,24.51268 -34.3858,24.51268 l 0,0 c -4.4983,-0.27887 -2.2705,-0.2557 -6.6835,-0.0832 -7.1549,0.82043 -14.2082,2.2831 -21.3712,3.01842 -8.4588,0.41571 -16.875,0.4574 -25.1925,-1.44511 -7.9363,-1.13986 -15.8946,-2.10277 -23.6526,-4.22438 -4.346,-1.05683 -8.4277,-2.78927 -12.7374,-3.91991 -8.3282,11.83295 -1.6139,2.11694 35.4553,-19.97193 0.2751,-0.16392 -0.623,-0.37313 -0.9238,-0.26351 -1.2278,0.44734 -0.5243,3.69435 -2.3244,3.69034 -16.0856,9.84732 -31.6378,20.81426 -49.554,26.77693 -7.0547,2.37812 -14.1964,2.43238 -21.1331,-0.56189 -9.3806,-4.93498 -17.3064,-11.87058 -24.648,-19.47175 -3.5874,-3.44562 -8.2842,-9.90164 -13.5991,-10.80905 -1.426,-0.24347 -3.2174,0.62019 -4.4549,1.07185 -7.5382,3.40557 -15.5198,5.9301 -23.8827,5.8744 -7.3585,-0.43691 -13.6695,-2.20171 -19.186,-7.37627 -4.8532,-4.55981 -9.3557,-9.54497 -14.5936,-13.65864 -14.6781,1.45207 -1.1423,0.2572 34.572,-20.39599 0.4969,-0.28735 -1.0843,0.42807 -1.5306,0.78899 -2.9886,2.41658 -4.1195,6.49333 -7.8995,8.10767 -24.7774,16.47891 -50.5112,31.70388 -77.4877,44.29146 -19.6349,8.01321 -40.3004,16.25041 -61.9154,13.62513 -2.3747,-0.6547 -4.7985,-1.15207 -7.1241,-1.96408 -9.8667,-3.44509 -18.6667,-9.62309 -27.8183,-14.51325 -7.51,-4.88251 -14.4619,-10.45687 -21.4618,-16.02273 -0.7771,-0.40729 -1.4822,-1.00062 -2.3311,-1.22186 -0.4588,-0.11957 -1.8058,0.49524 -1.4004,0.24941 11.6573,-7.06872 23.5403,-13.75932 35.2349,-20.76599 0.4105,-0.24593 -0.9893,0.16217 -1.3569,0.46853 -0.8923,0.74372 -1.6049,3.0297 -1.9425,3.88175 -1.4297,6.86309 -3.9632,13.39579 -6.5093,19.90981 -4.7047,10.01898 -9.6386,20.10956 -17.8734,27.78195 -13.4819,7.99434 -26.7895,16.29029 -40.4458,23.98303 -7.1077,4.00384 -15.9996,1.06351 -22.89081,-1.71136 0,0 35.45741,-23.32968 35.45741,-23.32968 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nothing we can do without the actual SVG/javascript code.

Comment: I added the init of the graph code. What else do you need for searching the issue? Thanks.

Comment: The simplest possible runnable example using the stackexchange run code facility or alternatively a jsfiddle would be ideal. And what do you mean by the svgs are not loaded?

Comment: Well jsfiddle would be way but would not really help I think. Because I think Firefox is not able to do that. Because Chrome is showing it really perfectly on the code. I think I will just ignore Firefox for now. Or showing huge PNG's which of course having issues when zooming, but ignoring that for now.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea why the graph is so laggy? And maybe why the markers are bugging with the strange line. I think Firefox is really strange behaving. If you really want a jsfiddle I will do one later on. Just say it. Till then thank you.

Comment: I doubt you'll get any answers without providing something that runs so we can all see the problem. You may be better off breaking this up into separate questions each focusing on a single issue with the simplest possible testcase you can make for each one.

Comment: Alright, I did a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/d2gjxy7n/2/ . It shows you that in chrome there is some svg happening but in firefox it's ignored.

Comment: Strange thing is that the arrows issues are not happening in jsfiddle. So I now tested in a Firefox on my Cloud instance and the arrow issue do not happen there, too. So this might be a local Firefox issue but a really ugly one if you ask me. Alright so just the SVG is now the only issue. Let's fix this =) Here a more cleaned version: http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/d2gjxy7n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ATux.svg` is not an SVG image. It's an html page that has a PNG image that shows what an SVG image would look like if you displayed it.

The SVG image you're looking for is `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Tux.svg` which can be found by clicking on the wikipedia page above.

Fixing that gives me penguins on the nodes which I assume is what you want. I imagine the other image has the same problem.

Your actual image is large and so you'll just see the top left corner which is blank. Adding a [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) to the SVG image file is probably what you'll need you'll need to experiment to get the right values for the viewBox.

Comment: Indeed, with your SVG it works (http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/d2gjxy7n/4/). But the problem is, I created another 2 SVG's (of course these here are just random from the internet) and made with Inkscape. So there might be a problem there with the SVG content. I will check my own SVG's content and come back if still having issues.

Comment: I downloaded that Tux.svg and it works. So it seems really an issue of my SVG files. You want me to post the SVG content here?

Comment: Are you serving them with the correct mime type? image/svg+xml if so posting the files is the only way forward

Comment: Yes the type is correct, I added an SVG non working example above. I already checked the Tux.svg, but it's very huge, but overall I have the same syntax. Btw that's the code Inkscape gave me.

Comment: The crazy thing is when I changed anything to a worse state in the SVG it is still fine in the Chrome. He is kind of ignoring all little issues, what is really amazing. I also checked my example in the IE, but there are not even shown the links/markers, and also the SVG's are not displayed like in the Firefox.

Comment: Checked my SVG now with http://validator.nu/ and got so many errors and warnings. So I think I need a better tool for creating valid SVG's =/

Comment: Okay, so it seems that Inscape creates invalide SVG code. I now created some simple stuff with http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/stable/editor/svg-editor.html and after a little fix that works now in Firefox. But still not shown in the IE. I think I will give up on showing SVG's and better show huge PNG's. This is too much I have to test and for sure not the only SVG problem I believe.

Comment: I now used Microsoft Visio and also complex SVGs are working. So yeah this software works also with the Firefox somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code, this is just guesswork:

[SVG Image with <image> tags does not show up in Firefox 16 when referred through GWT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935136/svg-image-with-image-tags-does-not-show-up-in-firefox-16-when-referred-through)

Basically, firefox doesn't like to use xlink:href elements, where a new request is issued for another resource. Might be worth investigating.

Comment: You've misunderstood the answers. That's about Firefox not loading external image file from within **image** files. Firefox will issue xlink:href for a new image just fine.

Comment: Another developer from my company also said that Firefox does not allow svg files in the images href link. He said the only way to do it is to put the source code into the href with an url() method. But I don't want to paste the svg data right into there. I think this is a poor solution.

Comment: As I said if you have an SVG document or SVG in html you can have it load external images. If those images themselves contain images then the contained images must be embedded. If you still don't understand, feel free to ask a specific question.